# How to extract additional infomation from Json Web Token JWT

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm working in a project apply Spring boot and JWT.
In OAuth2 configuration, I added more information into JWT sucessfully but I don't know how to extract this information when process a request contained my information.

Below is the code segment with I added my additional information:

```
public class CustomTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();
        additionalInfo.put("user_name", authentication.getName());
        User user = userService().getUserDetailsByLoginId(authentication.getName());
        additionalInfo.put("user_id", user.getRelationPartId());
        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

If you had experienced on it, please help me to get user_id from my token when process a request.

Thanks

Comment: If it's for Java it would be helpful if you added a corresponding tag as well

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got a solution, it works like a champ...
Below is some code segment, hope it help...

```
@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
}

@Bean
public TokenEnhancer customTokenEnhancer() {
    return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
}

@Bean
public DefaultAccessTokenConverter customAccessTokenConverter() {
    return new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
}

@Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(customTokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));

        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
                    .accessTokenConverter(customAccessTokenConverter())
                     .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
```

In Controller:

```
@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;

@ApiOperation(value = "test get security data", response = String.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUser1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getData1(OAuth2Authentication principal) {
    OAuth2AuthenticationDetails auth2AuthenticationDetails = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) principal.getDetails();
    Map<String, Object> details = tokenStore.readAccessToken(auth2AuthenticationDetails.getTokenValue()).getAdditionalInformation();
    String department= (String) details.get("department");
    return null;
}
```